# Meteor publications and subscription

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to learn Meteor, and currently trying to wrap my head around publications and subscriptions. I'm following the discover meteor book and one main point just doesn't make sense to me and was hoping some explanations in simple terms can be shared.

So a publication is what "fetches" the data from the mongo database to store within Meteor:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
   return Posts.find(); 
});
```

Then on the client side I subscribe to the publication. Woopy

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

What doesn't make sense is the Template Helpers. Originally Discover Meteor tells you to create an array of static posts that iterate through each post using a template helper. Well now that I'm turning things dynamically my template helper becomes:

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
    posts: function () {
        return Posts.find();
    }
});
```

What's the point of running the Posts.find() on both the server and client template helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts in publishing are server side collection. Posts in helpers are client-side collection which contains all published Posts. If you have thousands of posts you usually don't want to publish all Posts because it will take a few seconds to download the data.

You should publish just the data you need.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(limit) {
   return Posts.find({}, { limit: limit}); 
});
```

When you call this subscribe function, client-side collection Posts will contain just 100 posts.

```
var limit = 100;
Meteor.subscribe('posts', limit);
```

Comment: But why repeat the Posts.find() on both the client and server? Doesn't subscribe take the information from the database and store it on the client? Posts.find() is a database call is it not? Why make 2 calls?

Comment: Posts.find() on the server finds collections in MongoDB. Posts.find() on the client finds collections in minimongo (just data you published). You need to call Posts.find() on the client in order to get your published data.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So then whats the point of subscribe then? In your example you give the limit to how many posts will be outputted but wouldn't I do that in the template helper?

Comment: Template helper is client side code and it works with client side collections. If subscribe function is not called, there is no data in client side collection. You could publish/subscribe all posts and then filter them in client side collection. But if you have thousands of items in collection, publish/subscribe will take more time to load the data on the client.

Comment: ahh perfect explanation. Posts.find() on the server collects the info from the database. Meteor.subscribe() takes the info and stores in minimongo. Then Posts.find() on the client is only working with whats stored in the minimongo thanks to subscribe. So use case, I may only want to show 100 posts at a time. I would limit how much is outputted on the server side. But then if I only want to show 100 posts thats specific to a user per say I would do that on the client side.

Comment: Publish only data you need. It means if you need 100 items which belong to a specific user, you can publish Posts.find({userId: this.userId}, { limit: limit}); So every user can see only his data even if he calls Posts.find() in console.

Comment: So if I did Posts.find({userId: this.userId}, { limit: limit}); on the server and called Posts.find() in the template helper it's only going to give me the posts associated with the userId correct?

Comment: Yes. You can try to call Posts.find() in chrome/firebug console to see what data is published.

Answer (score 0):

In publications, you can setup exactly which Posts you want to store within the Posts collection on the client.

In your publish method, you could only return posts which contain the letter 'A'.

A typical use case is selecting objects which belongs to a user or a set of users.